Order of stability of adducts of boron halides with ammonia
Boron halides form an adduct in reacting with ammonia. For example $\ce{BF3 + NH3}$ gives $\ce{BF3-NH3}$ which is an acid base reaction. So the adduct formed by $\ce{BCl3}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ would be less stable than $\ce{BF3}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ since $\ce{BCl3}$ is a better Lewis acid. I would like to confirm if I am correct.

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103810/how-to-identify-the-most-stable-lewis-adduct-of-boron-trichloride https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142915/stability-of-pyridine-derivatives
